# Static method returning empty list in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to run a Django app on local server. It works fine on mu Ubuntu machine but in mac, I can't get the CSS for

```
localhost:8000/admin
```

and

```
localhost:8000/docs to load.
```

On digging further, I found out that the static URL in main "urls.py" file
return an empty list instead of a URL pattern.

Does anyone have an idea why it is like that on the new mac system?

Comment: Can you show your STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS and STATICFILES_FINDERS settings?

Comment: On your Mac, have you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Yes I have collected static.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue.  I was able to fix it manually by adding the following snippet to my urls.py file in the project (the urls.py file next to settings.py)...

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve
. . .
if settings.TESTING_PRODUCTION:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
        ]
```

I pulled this together from the [Django Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve).

I needed to do this so that I could test the "production" environment with manage.py runserver by manually setting DEBUG = False in settings.py which changes a few other URLs and also turns off trace printing in my code.

In my settings.py file, I have some code to set TESTING_PRODUCTION to True as well.  But in actual production with a real web server, the code should set TESTING_PRODUCTION to False so that the static files can be served by the webserver directly and not through Django.